# How can I create a sparse matrix representation of a dataset in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Assume that I have the following dataset:

```
CustomerID ItemID Quantity
236        512    2
236        372    3
245        512    5
245        129    2
245        326    3
251        372    5
251        629    3
```

I want to represent this dataset as a sparse matrix, where the rows are the `CustomerIDs`, the columns are the `ItemIDs` and the values in the matrix represent the `Quantity`. Thus, the final result should look like:

```
      (129) (326) (372) (512) (629)
(236) 0     0     3     2     0
(245) 2     3     0     5     0
(251) 0     0     5     0     3
```

My final matrix should have a shape of `(3 x 5)`. How can I achieve this, given that the customer and item IDs are large random numbers?

Comment: Have you looked at the Pandas sparse representation(s)?